# create non-padded thumb using ImageMagick

Tags: graphics, resize, imagemagick, thumbnails

I'm trying to create thumbs of an equal size, and I want no padding whatsoever. The thumb should be 154x208 pixels. The original can vary in shape and size.

I'm using ImageMagick, first I tried this:

> convert org.jpg -thumbnail 154x208 dest.jpg

This will create a thumbnail that is maximum 154 pix wide AND maximum 208 pix of height. I want an image that is 154x208 pixels though. Without padding.

I tried this:

> convert org.jpg -thumbnail x208 -crop 154x208+0+0 dest.jpg

This works great on an image in landscape mode, but a picture in portrait mode results in a thumb that's too narrow. -extent instead of -crop gives me the right end-result, but that ads padding to the thumbnail, and I don't want that.

I'm looking for a thumbnail from a picture that either has the full height and crops the width to fit, or the full width and crops the height, always resulting in a 154x208 thumbnail with no padding, using ImageMagick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by treating images with a smaller width-to-height ratio different from ones with a larger one:

a smaller width-to-height ratio than 154x200 image:

> convert org.jpg -thumbnail 154 -gravity center -crop 154x200+0+0 dest.jpg

and a higher ratio:

> convert org.jpg -thumbnail x208 -gravity center -crop 154x200+0+0 dest.jpg

It is an extra step in my coding, and I am still interested in an answer that doesn't need this extra step, but it does the job for now!